# How to create Toolbar app for Windows Taskbar, preferably with Python

Tags: python, windows, toolbar, taskbar

How to make an application that appears as a windows toolbar on the taskbar? Google wasn't helpful at all. Preferably I would like to do this with python, but since I am desperate any help would be appreciated. Exemplary apps (Lenovo Settings, HyperCam) that work in this manner are presented below:

[image]

Comment: [Creating Custom Explorer Bars, Tool Bands, and Desk Bands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099.aspx). Not for the faint at heart. And pretty much replaced in favor of [Thumbnail Toolbars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460.aspx#thumbbars) starting with Windows 7. Besides, asking whether something is possible and then move on to provide proof that it is doesn't make for a very good question. The answer to that question is: *"Yes, that's possible, as you have discovered already."*

Comment: Thanks, edited my question ;)